# My phone is not entering fastboot mode

Tags: adb, fastboot, bootloader

I just want to check whether bootloader is locked or unlocked. I am using **Minimal ADB and Fastboot** which I downloaded from [here](https://androidmtk.com/download-minimal-adb-and-fastboot-tool). I am following instructions to check bootloader from [this website](https://www.alphr.com/check-bootloader-is-unlocked/). Everything is fine until I enter into Fastboot mode on my phone. (I enabled USB Debugging and revoked usb debugging authorization in Developer Options). I can see my device after running `adb devices` in cmd. But when I run `adb reboot bootloader` command, it just reboots in normal mode. It doesn't enter to fastboot mode. I aslo tried `adb reboot fastboot` but it also didn't work. That means when I type `fastboot devices`, I don't see anything.

What should I do to enter Fastboot mode so that I can run `fastboot oem device-info` to see my bootloader information?

Note: My phone is Oppo F11 and it is running Android 11. I am not familiar with adb commands.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderland of Android. Every device model can be different. The main problem is to identify if this is an unusual problem of your device or if all Oppo F11 don't have fastboot mode. Unless by chance one of the other users owe an Oppo F11 you are out of luck here. There I would recommend you to better ask in the Oppo specific forum ad XDA developers forum. There the chance should be greater to meet someone with experience with your phone and who knows if this is normal bahavior or not.

Comment: @Robert Also my phone is not rooted. Can it be a reason?

Comment: No fastboot/bootloader mode works no matter if your phone is rooted or not.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3929505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oppo F11 has non-unlockable bootloader, fastboot is disabled intentionally. You can root with [bootless-root](https://www.xda-developers.com/mediatek-su-rootkit-exploit) method only, but carefully read instructions especially respect all warnings

Comment: Thanks alot man. I needed to know it because I think my oppo f11 has any undetectable malware or backdoor and someone said if a phone is running stock ROM and bootloader is locked, those kinda virus will be gone if you reset your phone.